# How to convert DateTime<UTC> to DateTime<FixedOffset> or vice versa?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I have a struct that contains a timestamp.
For that I am using the [chrono library](https://lifthrasiir.github.io/rust-chrono/chrono/). There are two ways to get the timestamp:

1. Parsed from a string via `DateTime::parse_from_str` which results in a `DateTime<FixedOffset>`
2. The current time, received by `UTC::now` which results in a `DateTime<UTC>`.

Is there a way to convert `DateTime<UTC>` to `DateTime<FixedOffset>`?

Comment: You really should be including some amount of example code. As it is right now, any answerer needs to create some arbitrary amount of code that uses the chrono crate which may or may not match the code you have. Please read about creating an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for [`DateTime::with_timezone`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.9/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.with_timezone):

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Local, TimeZone, Utc}; // 0.4.9

fn main() {
    let now = Utc::now();
    let then = Local
        .datetime_from_str("Thu Jul  2 23:26:06 EDT 2015", "%a %h %d %H:%M:%S EDT %Y")
        .unwrap();

    println!("{}", now);
    println!("{}", then);

    let then_utc: DateTime<Utc> = then.with_timezone(&Utc);

    println!("{}", then_utc);
}
```

I've added a redundant type annotation on `then_utc` to show it is in UTC. This code prints

```
2019-10-02 15:18:52.247884539 UTC
2015-07-02 23:26:06 +00:00
2015-07-02 23:26:06 UTC
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, i didn't post sample code but yours actually solves my problem. I didn't see that and i was trying to figure out by the API docs...  Now that i see it, it seems obvious.

Comment: Great example!  However, this does not handle `DateTime<FixedOffset>` (which of course is a distinct type from `Utc` and `Local`).

Answer (score 3):

You will want to do the following:

```rust
Utc::now().with_timezone(&FixedOffset::east(0))
```

You are basically converting Utc to FixedOffset with zero offset. Some of us complained about having a more obvious solution and a PR seems to be afoot.

Answer (score 2):

[Micheal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74038013/2926992) is not valid today. [FixedOffset::east](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.23/chrono/offset/struct.FixedOffset.html#method.east) is deprecated as it might point to an out-of-bounds seconds space on the globe.

[FixedOffset::east_opt](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/struct.FixedOffset.html#method.east_opt) is preferred today. It returns an `Option<FixedOffset>`. It is `None` if it points to out-of-bounds.

An example code:

```
Utc::now().with_timezone(&FixedOffset::east_opt(0).unwrap())
```

We can unwrap this safely (without the fear of panic) because zero seconds will never point to an out-of-bounds location.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from a Local DateTime (FixedOffset, or TimeZoned) to UTC like this:

```
// Construct a Timezone object, we will use it later to build
// some DateTimes, but it is not strictly required for the
// conversion code
let tz_timezone = Tz::from_str(input_string_timezone)
    .expect("failed to convert string to chrono tz");

// Create a DateTime::<Utc>
let utc_now = Utc::now();
println!("utc_now: {}", utc_now);

// Create a Local (Timezoned) DateTime
let naive_datetime = utc_now.naive_local();
let london_now = tz_timezone.from_local_datetime(&naive_datetime).unwrap();
println!("london_now: {}", london_now);

// Asside: We can do this another way too
let london_now = chrono_tz::Europe::London.from_local_datetime(&naive_datetime).unwrap();
println!("london_now: {}", london_now);

// The actual conversion code from local timezone time to UTC timezone time
let london_now_utc = Utc.from_utc_datetime(&london_now.naive_utc());
println!("london_now_utc: {}", london_now_utc);

// Bonus: calculate time difference
let difference_from_utc = london_now_utc - utc_now;
println!("difference_from_utc: {}", difference_from_utc);
```

---

You can also just use `try_from`.

```
let fixed_offset_datetime: DateTime<chrono::FixedOffset> = ...
let utc_datetime = DateTime::<Utc>::try_from(fixed_offset_datetime)?;
```

Answer (score -1):

because DateTime implements From<Utc> for DateTime<FixedOffset> you can simply call .into() to convert between the two:

```
let now_utc = Utc::now();
let now_fixed: DateTime<FixedOffset> = now_utc.into()
```

Comment: Your answer applies conversion Utc to FixedOffset, but not vice versa.

Comment: the text of the original question asked specifically about converting in this one direction: "Is there a way to convert DateTime<UTC> to DateTime<FixedOffset>?", though the title of the question did add "or vice versa". Both types implement From/Into for one another so the answer is still the same - just use .into() plus a type specification.