# Compare DateTime with fixed offset to DateTime with time zone

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

How does one convert between `DateTime<FixedOffset>` and `DateTime<Tz>`, in order to subtract to get a duration, compare inequality, or reassign?

```rust
use chrono::DateTime;
use chrono_tz::America::New_York;

fn main() {
    let mut a = DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339("2022-06- 01T10:00:00").unwrap();
    let b = a.with_timezone(&New_York);
    a = b;
}
```

An attempt to do this directly yields the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:9
   |
11 |     let mut a = DateTime::parse_from_rfc3339("2022-06-01T10:00:00").unwrap();
   |                 ------------------------------------------------------------ expected due to this value
12 |     let b = a.with_timezone(&New_York);
13 |     a = b;
   |         ^ expected struct `FixedOffset`, found enum `Tz`
   |
   = note: expected struct `DateTime<FixedOffset>`
              found struct `DateTime<Tz>`
```

[Playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b?code=%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Achrono%20%3D%20%220.4.19%22%0Achrono-tz%20%3D%20%220.6.1%22%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20chrono%3A%3ADateTime%3B%0Ause%20chrono_tz%3A%3AAmerica%3A%3ANew_York%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20a%20%3D%20DateTime%3A%3Aparse_from_rfc3339(%222022-06-01T10%3A00%3A00%22).unwrap()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20a.with_timezone(%26New_York)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20a%20%3D%20b%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert DateTime<UTC> to DateTime<FixedOffset> or vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186864/how-to-convert-datetimeutc-to-datetimefixedoffset-or-vice-versa)

Comment: It doesn't, sadly. with_timezone yields a Tz.

Comment: I suppose it's helpful because no one really knows how to convert between these types...they know only how to hack around with autocomplete and google. Why is rust so complicated? When converting between datetimes requires trial-and-error, something has gone very wrong.

Comment: "Why is rust so complicated?" [*Time* is complicated.](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the timezone of `b` into the timezone of `a` before assigning it:

```rust
a = b.with_timezone(&a.timezone());
```

Comment: This incurs a runtime penalty: is it possible to avoid this?